# AS3 > Mouse Event not happening?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, box2d

**Background:** Trying to make a ball appear in the same location the mouse is positioned. Using Box2D Library. Working on a class file (.as)

**Issue:** The mouse event does not work (I click but nothing happens) . No output errors whatsoever. :(

**Mouse Event** EDIT: Marty Wallace corrected my code, but still the mouse event won't work.

```
   private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
            {
                sim.addCircle({x:mouseX, y:mouseY, radius:0.25, density:5});
                sim.start();
```

**Full Code:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    [SWF(width = 350, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

    public class MouseTest extends MovieClip {

        public var sim:QuickBox2D;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function MouseTest()
        {
            sim = new QuickBox2D(this);  
            sim.createStageWalls();

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
        }

        /**
         * ..
         * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
         */
        private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            sim.addCircle({x:mouseX, y:mouseY, radius:0.25, density:5});
            sim.start();  

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT by Gabriel Meono:**

> > QuickBOX2D uses meters instead of pixels. To work with pixels with this library, one must divide each number by 30. I simply added a `"/3"` to the `mouseX` / `mouseY` and it worked!
> >     I updated your code, thanks!

Either do this (recommended):

```
public var sim:QuickBox2D;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function MouseTest()
{
    sim = new QuickBox2D(this);  
    sim.createStageWalls();

    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
}

/**
 * ..
 * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
 */
private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
{
    sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(mouseY/30), density:5});
    sim.start();  
}
```

Or this (not so recommended, but closer to your code):

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function MouseTest()
{
    var sim:QuickBox2D = new QuickBox2D(this);  
    sim.createStageWalls();

    addEventListener(
        MouseEvent.CLICK,
        function(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(mouseY/30), radius:0.25, density:5});
            sim.start();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: QuickBOX2D uses meters instead of pixels. To work with pixels with this library, one must divide each number by 30. I simply added a "/30" to the mouseX/mouseY and it worked! I updated your code, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring the `clicked` function outside the MouseTest function.

Comment: `sim` needs to be declared as a class member also.